# taking the absolute value of complex numbers to an arbitrary power

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value

I need $|\frac{i^{n}}{n}|$ and I have seen the problem simplified to $\frac{|i^{n}|}{n}$ and I am confused by this as isn't $\frac{1}{n}$ the coefficient of i so we could just square it and take the square root to find the absolute value. Further I do then not understand how $|i^{n}| = 1$

Comment: A good starting point is to begin with $$i^1,i^2,i^3,i^4,i^5,...$$

Comment: Isn't $n$ a natural number? If so, then it for sure positive.. So $|n|=n$

Comment: Is the equality $\left\lvert\frac{i^n}n\right\rvert=\frac{\lvert i^n\rvert}n$ that confused you? Your question is not clear.

Comment: yes that is correct ^

Comment: If $z=x+iy$ is a complex number, $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Now what are $x,y$ for $z=i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure I get your question. What do you mean by "isn't $\frac{1}{n}$ the reciprocal of i?
In general, it holds that:
$\vert z_1z_2 \vert = \vert z_1\vert\vert z_2\vert$
and $\vert z_1^{n} \vert = \vert z_1 \vert^{n}$.
If $z_1 = \frac{1}{n}, z_2=i^{n}$ and use of property 1 followed by property 2 gives:
$ \frac{|i|^{n}}{|n|}$, and I take it that n is non-negative so you might remove the modulus from the denominator.

Comment: Apologies I meant coefficient.

Comment: The absolute value of **any** power of i is 1.

Comment: How is it that you have gone from $|\frac{1}{n}|$ to $\frac{1}{|n|}$? Is this a rule?

Comment: @Jlatmer you have that $| \frac{1}\{n}| = \frac{|1|}{|n|}$ (this is a rule), and $|1|=1$